# Error while trying to sync - ArcGIS Collector App

Tags: feature-service, arcgis-collector

One of my staff is trying to sync edits from the ArcGIS Collector App and keeps getting the attached error message. I, and many other staff, are able to sync edits without issues. She has tried several times on WiFi and on LTE (with sync enabled with data) without success. Anyone have any ideas about this error message?

[image]

Comment: The thread below might be able to help with your issue: https://geonet.esri.com/thread/90833 There are a number of workarounds listed.

Comment: Please always provide error messages as text rather than just a picture so that they are available to future searches.